# No more xercesxmldom unit in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, xerces, xmldom

I'm wondering what happened to the `xercesxmldom` unit as one of the [XML DOM implementations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model).
It seems to have disappeared in [Delphi XE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Main_Page).
Why?

(I searched the docs; couldn't find any relevant info on xercesxmldom disappearing).

**Edit**: these are the sources I have archived:

```
R:\>dir /s /b xercesxmldom.pas
R:\D2006-Enterprise-D10-BDS-4.0\source\Win32\xml\xercesxmldom.pas
R:\D2007-Enterprise-D11-RadStudio-5.0\source\Win32\xml\xercesxmldom.pas
R:\D2009-Enterprise-D12-RadStudio-6.0\source\Win32\xml\xercesxmldom.pas
R:\D2010-Enterprise-D14-RadStudio-7.0\source\Win32\xml\xercesxmldom.pas
R:\D7.01.Architect\Source\Xml\xercesxmldom.pas
```

Nothing in the `R:\DXE-Enterprise-D15-RadStudio-8.0` source tree...

--jeroen

Comment: It would be so nice is people added a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Maybe somebody was shocked by the `dir /s /b` now that we've got "Everything"? http://www.voidtools.com/  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quote the [answer](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=314469#314469) that [Bruneau (Jean-Marie) Babet](https://forums.embarcadero.com/profile.jspa?userID=3541) posted to [my question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=314209) on the Embarcadero forums:

> I asked: the removal was intentional
>   and driven by the fact that we had 
>   little evidence that the xerces DOM
>   was being used, the cost of the effort
>   to port it to the Mac and the maturity
>   of ADOM. I was told that we would be 
>   open to releasing our xerces wrappers
>   (say on SourceForge) if there's 
>   interest.

So if you are using xerces in Delphi, then either wait for the wrappers to appear on sourceforge, or switch do the [OpenXML ADOM](http://tp.embarcadero.com/partnercentral.exe/choseproduct?pid=KKWGWO) which is compatible with Delphi XE.

Answer (score 0):

It's in my install of RAD Studio <strike>XE</strike> 2010. The source file is in:

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\Win32\xml\
```

I don't see it in XE's source path anywhere, so it does appear they've removed it for some reason.

A quick scan of the source code in the 2010 version, however, doesn't reveal anything that would prevent it's being used in XE. I haven't tested that, however.

Comment: RAD Studio `7.0` is `Delphi 2010`, `Delphi XE` is ...\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\`8.0`\...

Comment: Thank goodness they switched from these confusing incremental version numbers to something less confusing... oh, wait a minute...  ;)

Comment: @Jeroen: You're right, of course. I did a scan of my drive for xercesxmldom.*, and mistakenly took the Embarcadero\Rad Studio referenced folder as XE. Corrected.